# Asignación de nombres automático en base a información previa

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un formulario para dar altas, en dicho formulario quiero asignar el nombre de forma automática con la siguiente estructura: "MDF+sitio+numero (1,2,..n)",esto último va de acuerdo al registro.

MDF, es un valor fijo y quiero tomarlo de un input previo y lo tengo como readonly, el sitio también lo tengo en readonly y se asigna en automático cuando se selecciona una unidad, y por ultimo el número quiero que sea incremental. no tengo idea de como hacerlo, quise probar con js para asignarlo como le hice en la parte de unidad y sitio pero no pude :c

```js
// Función que se ejecuta cada vez que se selecciona una unidad.
function cambioUnidad()
{ document.getElementById('showSitio').value=document.getElementById('unidad').value;
}
```

```html
    <tr>
          <td><label for="unidad"><strong>Unidad donde se encuentra el MDF:</strong></label></td>
          <td>
        <select name="unidad" id='unidad' onchange='cambioUnidad();' required>
            <option value="">Seleccione Unidad:</option>
            <option value="1454">Almacén Delegacional Puebla</option>
            <opton value="40012">Area de Auditoria, Quejas y Responsabilidades</opton>
            <option value="70261">CECEM Bosques de Manzanilla</option>
            <option value="1465">CECEM Izúcar</option>
            <option value="70262">CECEM Lomas de San Miguel</option>
            <option value="70259">CECEM San Martín Texmelúcan</option>
            <option value="70263">CECEM Tehuacán</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="sitio"><strong>Sitio:</strong></label></td>
          <td>
        <!-- input donde se mostrara el sitio -->
        <input type='text' id='showSitio' readonly>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="area"><strong>Área:</strong></label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="area" id="area" value="MDF" readonly>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="localizacion"><strong>Localización de MDF:</strong></label></td></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="localizacion" id="localizacion" required       
        placeholder="Ej. Farmacia."></tr>
          <tr>
          <td><label for="nombre"><strong>Nombre de MDF:</strong></label></td></td>
          **<td><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" readonly>**
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: Este registro lo vas a guardar en una BD? o cómo tendrás el control del número que quieres que sea incremental?

Comment: Sí, se guardaría en una BD.

Comment: Utiliza AJAX para hacer una consulta a tu BD y traer el ultimo registro de tu ID incremental y ese número lo concatenas al input **Nombre de MDF:**.